# Need to set a comman library file for all projects of a single solution Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I need some help to add a .*lib file for my solution and this solution has many projects.
I am going to make it more clear. Lets i have a "ABC.sln" solution in visual studio 2010. This ABC.sln has several projects (VC++ Project (1,2,3....*vcxproj) and these 1, 2 and 3 projects required a 123comman.lib file in the linker option of their respective  projects.

Currently i add this library file in all three projects and it works fine but i think there must be some way to set this library file as a common stuff for all projects inside a solution. So that i just set it once and all projects can share it.

Is it possible ? if yes how can we do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: the external property sheet is the best way to share building rules across multiple project, but when you want apply a change in a lot of project store in the same folder or au folder, you can also use a text editor like notepad++ to replace in every .vcproj the <AdditionalLibrarie> by <AdditionalLibrarie>commonLib.lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 introduced the concept of Property Pages, which is distinct and separate from Project Settings.  Property Pages are similar to Project Settings in that you can specify things like additional dependencies, language rules, optimization settings, etc.  But unlike Project Settings, Property Pages use a different file to store these settings, and these files can be shared across all (or any) projects in your solution.

Documentation for Property Pages is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/675f1588.aspx) -- I'll leave the details up to you.  But to get started, go to **View** > **Property Manager**, open up one of your projects, create a new property page for a given platform (x64 Debug, x64 Release, etc), and set your settings.  Then you can use this Property Page in your other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Projects can share configuration via property sheets. You can create them in the project configuration tree by right-clicking a project and selecting "add property sheet" or something like that (been a while). In a property sheet, you can specify the import, and then you can add the property sheet to all other projects as well.

This does not reduce the initial work: you still have to add something to every project. Solutions do not have the ability to inject anything into projects; they're a completely different file format.

However, it does save you work if you then have to do another task that is common to all projects, like changing the library name you want to include, or adding another library. Then you only have to do it once, in the property sheet.

Comment: Ah, property page was the name of that thing. It's been more than a year since I last used VS.

Answer (score 1):

Make a NuGet package out of this library, and use the package manager to add the dll to all projects.

An in-depth description of how to generate a NuGet package for C++ code can be found [here](http://coapp.org/tutorials/autopackage-guide.html).

If you do it this way, it only takes a single click per project (to enable the checkbox when adding the package in package manager) to add the library as dependency.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is only about sharing the same file among different projects in a single solution. You can add the file at solution level and then do add existing items in individual projects and choose to add them as link.

This way you have only one copy of file that is shared.